# How to convert array<struct> to array<string>

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the below schema

```
root
|-- ColA: array
|--|--element: struct
|--|--|--id: string (nullable = true)
|--|--|--name: string (nullable = true)
```

The schema of the expected dataframe would be,

```
root
|-- ColA: array
|--|--element: string (continsNull = true)
```

Is it possible to convert an array of struct to array of strings?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the field `name`, you can just select that array column as usual

```py
(df
    .withColumn('ColA', F.col('ColA.name'))
    .printSchema()
)

# Input
+----------------+
|            ColA|
+----------------+
|[{1, A}, {2, B}]|
+----------------+

# Output
+------+
|  ColA|
+------+
|[A, B]|
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRANSFORM` expression:

```py
expr = "TRANSFORM(ColA, x -> to_json(x))"
df = df.withColumn('ColA', f.expr(expr))

df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- ColA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+------------------------------------------------------+
|ColA                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"id":"1","name":"Hello"}, {"id":"2","name":"World"}]|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```